# Nest thermostat E keeps running

Tags: thermostat, nest

I have a nest thermostat E for a year or so, but recently it feels like it keeps running for a a prolonged time when the vent is not venting hot air anymore, worth to mention is that, it DOES bring the temperature up, but it feels like after the room temperature gets to the target, it still keeps running for prolonged time. Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: The thermostat is running? Or do you mean that it's keeping the furnace running? How far above the set point is the temperature getting? Is it unusually cold outside? This will tend to make the furnace run longer than you're used to.

Comment: Yes the thermostat is running. Say if I change the target temp to 70, and current room temp is 65, it can brings the furnace up and there is warm air, but the problem is that it seems when it gets 69, it struggles to get to 70 so it keeps blowing air, but at this time the furnace has been turned off and the vent is blowing non-warm air. It is usually cold outside recently. If this is normal, I guess question will be why it still keep the fan running while the furnace has stopped?